# How to solve multiple variable equality?

Tags: linear-algebra

Generate **integer** triplets $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies the condition $$2x+2=3y=4z+2$$After a little trial and error, I found out that one solution is $(2,2,1)$. How to determine if such a solution exists at all? If it exists, is there a generic way to obtain such solution so that I could code it as a program.

Comment: maybe $2x+2=3y=4z+2$?

Comment: Yes @gimusi, thanks for pointing that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$2x+2=3y \implies x=\frac32y-1 \implies y=2k$$

then

$$4z+2=3y=6k \implies z=\frac32k-\frac12 \implies k=2h+1$$

then for $h\in \mathbb Z$

- $x=6h+2$
- $y=4h+2$
- $z=3h+1$

Comment: When (x,y,z) is substituted in the initial equation, we get 12h = 12h = 12h+6.

Comment: @AShanmukhaBruhadroop Yes a typo! I fix

Comment: now z does not return an integer value @gimusi

Comment: @AShanmukhaBruhadroop Now it should be ok!

Comment: that's great! How do I find this out in a generic manner? Also, let's say we have n equations for n variables, how to determine all of them? @gimusi

Comment: let's say we introduce another variable as suggested by gandalf61 how do you determine that the introduced variable has to take the form of 12h+6?

Comment: @AShanmukhaBruhadroop We have used a direct method since the system is simple we have obtained at first the condition on$ y$ in order to obtain $x$ integer, that is $y=2k$ i.e. $y$ even. Then we did the same for $z$ which lead to $k=2h+1$ that is $k$ odd. The conditions turned out to be compatible and thus we have find the solution. For a more general system we can try to proceed in the same way with some semplification if needed in order to have a system as simpler as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can write $$2x+2=3y$$ and $$3y=4z+2$$ so you will get one system of equations
$$2x+2-3y=0$$
$$4z+2-3y=0$$

Comment: There was a small typo and the question was edited. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a parameter $t$ defined by
$t=2x+2=3y=4z+2$

Then each triple $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies the original equation can be expressed in terms of $t$ as follows

$(x,y,z) = (\frac{t-2}{2},\frac{t}{3}, \frac{t-2}{4})$

There is nothing unique about the parameter $t$; if you replace $t$ by $12h+6$ then you get the paramaterisation in gimusi's answer.

Comment: which means 12 is LCM(2,3,4) @gandalf61

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how did you get 12h+6? @gandalf61

Comment: Indeed we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Yes @gimusi we have infinitely many solutions. We are only filtering out those that produce an integer.

Comment: @AShanmukhaBruhadroop Also on teh integers we have infinitely many (but countable) solutions.